Gitlab Markdown Table layout
In gitlab wiki I have this table (MWE).
I want to make a rowheader "collspan" of the research row.
I am open to do this with a double horizontal line, or via a colspan, or via somehting else.
This MWE notation of ||| does not render into colspan.
I don't know how to change a row background color or do in markdown the alternative for \hline\hline.
How can I create a visual way to communicate that the research row is a section delimters in the table?
|              | Backlog  | Ideation  | Creation  | Production |
| :------      | :------  | :------   | :------   | :------    |
| **Research** |||||
|              |          |           | bla       |            |


You should probably inclue an image or ascii art of what you wish the result to look like.

maybe you can hilight the "research" term by using ==research== (== for hilighting)
BUT i don't know if GitLab can make hilighting :/
